# Handle copy event on whole app level, Angular9

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on an Angular9 app. There are some cases that when use double click any text/label on any part of page, and copy that, Chrome by default add some non-printable characters in copied text.

so i thinking that, if there is some global copy event service which i can inject in the main app.module and onCopy, i can replace the non-printable text from the copied text.

Please advice how can i acheive that. In javascript i found somehting like this:

```
document.addEventListener('copy', (event) => {
    console.log('copy action initiated')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Rxjs.

```
const source$ = fromEvent(document, 'copy');
```

And now just subscribe.

```
let subscription = source$.subscribe (copy => 
{
const selection = document.getSelection();
event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', selection.toString().toUpperCase());
event.preventDefault();

console.log(copy) 
});
```

And dont forget to cancel the subscription in your, ie, ngOnDestroy.

Comment: how can i get copied text, the copy is only the event

Comment: The Event is an object. You can find the text copied inside.

Comment: Updated! You have to retrieve the selection and update the clipboardData. Copy is just the Event that fires when the user performs a Ctrl+C or selects “Copy” from contextual menu...but nothing more.